# LiveAgent create a case and show it in EDIT mode, where the agent can go add more information

Tags: liveagent

I have the read documentation multiple times, I am able to create the Case with the information from prechat form, show the created Case, but I want the Case to be shown in EDIT mode where in agent can go add additional information.

Any tips on how this can be done.

Comment: did you find any solution to do this?

Comment: No, still looking for it.

Comment: Did you find any solution to do this? Or somebody else maybe ? :)